# How to properly add RequestContexts

Tags: gwt, request

what i'm trying to do is gather several request all together and fire them once
my code  :

```
RequestContext contextA =requestFactory
        .dataRequest().save(...).to(...);
RequestContext contextB =requestFactory
        .itemRequest().save(...).to(...);
requestA.append(requestB);
requestA.fire();
```

dataRequest and item request both extends RequestContext

when im trying to do this like that i got:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   The provided RequestContext has been changed 
>  at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.append(AbstractRequestContext.java:484)

so what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `append()` must be *clean* `RequestContext`.

You can change your code to:

```
ItemRequest contextB = requestFactory.itemRequest();
contextA.append(contextB);
contextB.save(...).to(...);
```

or more simply:

```
requestA.append(requestFactory.itemRequest()).save(...).to(...);
```

**Rationale**: internally, appended `RequestContext`s use a shared *state*; when calling `append()`, the internal state of the appended `RequestContext` is replaced with the one you're appending to. If it's not empty, you'd lose data (there's no merging), so it simply fails.